# Angular: How to apply validation directives to a child of the custom template

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular-components, angular-validation

I'm trying to create a custom Angular component that wraps existing Form components into a single component e.g. instead of having a label, text box, validation error spans, I have a component that renders all three together and manages the validation state automatically. For instance, when the field validation passes, the error message and css is cleared. All of that is wrapped in component called my-text-component:

```
<div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': (invalid | async), 'form-group--disabled': (disabled) }">
    <label class="input-label" [attr.for]="identifier">{{ label }}
        <!--Removed for brevity -->
    </label>
    <div #inputGroup class="input-group">
        <span *ngIf="icon" class="input-group-addon">
             <span svg-icon ....
            </span>
        </span>
        <input #formControl (keyup)="onKeyUp($event)" (keydown)="onKeyDown($event)"
               type="{{ type }}"
               class="form-control input-sm"
               placeholder="{{ placeholder }}"
               [id]="identifier"
               [name]="name"
               [disabled]="disabled"

               //How do I add custom validators here dynamically?
        />
        <!-- Other customisations -->
    </div>    
</div>
```

In my component class:

```
@Component ({
    selector: 'custom-text',
    templateUrl: 'custom-text.component.html',
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,

})
export class CustomTextComponent implements ....{

    @Input()
    @Optional()
    customValidators: Array<any>

    constructor(renderer: Renderer, renderer2: Renderer2) {
        //Initializations
    }

    //How do I access validators set on <custom-text> and apply them dynamically?
    onInit() {

    }

}
```

What I would like to be able to do is apply the inbuilt angular validators on this component and somehow wire them up to the input element e.g, doing something like this:

```
<custom-text required minlength="4" pattern="some pattern">
</custom-text>
```

should apply the validators `required`, `minlength` and `pattern` to the input box inside the template for `custom-text`. How do I achieve this?

I'm thinking of specifying an optional input variable that takes an array of validators and sets its on the input element dynamically - not sure if that is the right way though?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Problem! If you want to add the validators like required dynamicaly you can bind them like this [readonly]="IsReadOnly" to a property in your code.

Here the example:
The Properties in the Typescript class:

```
 IsReadOnly = false;
 IsRequired = false;
```

The Funktion to set the Properties

```
 public setField(field: LayoutFieldVO): FormControl {
    this.field = field;
    this.IsReadOnly = field.readOnly;
    this.IsRequired = field.required;
    this.MinLength = field.minLength;
    if(this.IsRequired)
      this.lfvalidation = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);
    else
      this.lfvalidation = new FormControl('', []);
    return this.lfvalidation
  }
```

In my example I also create FormControl to bind them to the Control and that I can check the View if they are all valid.

The Binding in the HTML

```
<input matInput [(ngModel)]=model[bindinginfo] [readonly]="IsReadOnly" [required]="IsRequired" [formControl]="lfvalidation">
```